# Java Swing/IntelliJ IDEA Plugin: How to resolve 'Slow operations are prohibited on EDT' error when using file chooser Dialog

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a plugin in IntelliJ IDEA using Jetbrains plugin SDK.
I have created a Dialog box that shows a button to select a Directory.
In the ActionListener of the button, I am calling FileChooser dialog. After i select a directory from this dialog, i get the following error

```
java.lang.Throwable: Slow operations are prohibited on EDT. See SlowOperations.assertSlowOperationsAreAllowed javadoc.
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:376)
    at com.intellij.util.SlowOperations.assertSlowOperationsAreAllowed(SlowOperations.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecordsImpl.update(FSRecordsImpl.java:718)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findChildInfo(PersistentFSImpl.java:598)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findInPersistence(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.doFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.refreshAndFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:352)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.refreshAndFindFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:129)
    at com.intellij.ui.PathChooserDialogHelper$Companion.fileToVirtualFile(PathChooserDialogHelper.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.ui.PathChooserDialogHelper$Companion.access$fileToVirtualFile(PathChooserDialogHelper.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.ui.PathChooserDialogHelper.fileToVirtualFile(PathChooserDialogHelper.kt:47)
    at com.intellij.ui.PathChooserDialogHelper.getChosenFiles(PathChooserDialogHelper.kt:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.mac.MacPathChooserDialog.choose(MacPathChooserDialog.java:131)
    at com.intellij.ui.mac.MacPathChooserDialog.choose(MacPathChooserDialog.java:171)
    at com.intellij.ui.mac.MacPathChooserDialog.choose(MacPathChooserDialog.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:38)
```

This is how I am adding the FileChooser dialog in the button's ActionListener

```
    JButton directorySelectorButton = new JButton("", AllIcons.Nodes.Folder);
        directorySelectorButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            FileChooserDescriptor descriptor = new FileChooserDescriptor(false, true, false, false, false, false);
            VirtualFile[] chosenFiles = FileChooser.chooseFiles(descriptor, null, null);

            System.out.println(chosenFiles[0].getPath());
        });
```

Comment: Hi. You can also post this question to the official JetBrains forum dedicated to plugin development and OpenAPI: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development